# Sort and concatenate values by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I've got a list of Groups and Names, as seen in DF below.  I'm looking to arrange this list alphabetically and concatenate each name separated by a comma, as seen in DF2 below.  I thought this would be simple, but it is proving to be more challenging than expected!

```
DF <- tibble::data_frame(
    Group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
    Name = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A"))

DF2 <- tibble::data_frame(
    Group = c(1, 2, 3), 
    Name = c("A, B, C", "A, B", "A, B, C"))
```

I'd appreciate any help in solving this to account for an unknown number of names listed per group, either with or without a dplyr pipeline.

Thanks!

Comment: How is `DF %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarize(Comb = paste(Name[order(Name)], collapse = ","))`?

Comment: @Abdou Or `DF %>% arrange(Name) %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarize(Comb = toString(Name))`

Comment: @Frank oh that's gooood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[order(Name), .(Comb = toString(Name)) , by = Group]
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```
aggregate(Name~Group, DF, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ","))

#  Group  Name
#1     1 A,B,C
#2     2   A,B
#3     3 A,B,C
```